# How to generate a github-like Impact Graph?

Tags: git, graph, github

Is there some program out there (or some magical git plugin I've missed) to get an impact graph or something similar from a git repo without going through github? I'm unsure where I'd begin exactly to write my own, as far as data collection goes (I can generate graphs). I assume there's some flags I could pass to git-log to get commits and authors, but I'm unsure how to get impact (sum of lines added/removed, or maybe total bytes added/removed), and perhaps even skip certain files from consideration.

Answer (score 7):

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265040/how-to-count-total-lines-changed-by-a-specific-author-in-a-git-repository) provides some answers:

```
git log --author="<authorname>" --pretty=tformat: --numstat
```

and for the graph itself, I know about this **[jQuery program](http://dmitry.baranovskiy.com/work/github/impact-code.js)** (but I haven't tested it), based on json-formatted data. [Illustrated here](http://dmitry.baranovskiy.com/work/github/), [reported by this message](https://fedorahosted.org/pipermail/ekg/2009-March/000105.html))

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I too, came to this question hoping to find an easy answer and found none.

Fear not! I have fixed the problem.

Check out https://github.com/jtolds/git-impact

New project, generates nice interactive impact graphs from a git repo.

(x-posted to [Is there an "impact graph" tool for non-GitHub projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347652/is-there-an-impact-graph-tool-for-non-github-projects), should these questions be merged?)