# Is there an "impact graph" tool for non-GitHub projects?

Tags: git, github

Are there any tools to build an [impact graph](http://github.com/blog/159-one-more-thing) like that of GitHub's, that can be run on repos that aren't on GitHub? Maybe something that spits out a nice PNG or a `<canvas>`-based HTML file?

Answer (score 5):

Raphaël.js is a JavaScript library for manipulationg interactive SVG. They have a demo that is an impact graph : http://raphaeljs.com/github/impact.html

Answer (score 3):

The only platform I know of which could produce such a graph would be **[Hudson](https://web.archive.org/web/20200117140447/http://www.hudson-ci.org:80/)** and [its many plugins](https://web.archive.org/web/20171028101620/http://wiki.hudson-ci.org:80/display/HUDSON/Plugins).

The [Static Code Analysis Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Static+Code+Analysis+Plug-ins), for instances, produces fairly advance graphs.

[image]
<sub>(source: [hudson-ci.org](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/download/attachments/31457291/graph-difference.png?version=1&modificationDate=1242231043000))</sub>

None of the plugins propose exactly what you are looking for, but, combined with the [Git Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Git+Plugin), it is a start for creating new graphs.

---

Another solution (not free except for open-source projects) would be an [online code tracker like FishEye](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077772/online-software-tracking-software/3078611#3078611).

It has [Graphs generation capabilities](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHEYE/FishEye+Charts) which are quite complete and much closer of what you want (but again, commercial product).

[image]

or:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I too, came to this question hoping to find an easy answer and found none.

Fear not! I have fixed the problem.

Check out https://github.com/jtolds/git-impact

New project, generates nice interactive impact graphs from a git repo.

Comment: (x-posted to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673052/how-to-generate-a-github-like-impact-graph, should these questions be merged?)