# Is there any way to embed any of the graphs from Github in HTML?

Tags: html, github

Is there any way to embed any of the graphs from Github (any of the 4 found at https://github.com/Vizzuality/CartoDB-SQL-API/graphs)? For example, [this one](https://github.com/Vizzuality/CartoDB-SQL-API/graphs/code-frequency) showing the changes in the lines of code.

Since the structure of the page is consistent, I'm pretty sure I can scrape it, but that's a bit cheeky at best. Note that I want the image itself - not the whole page - that is contained in the div:

```html
<div class="graphs wheader">
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347652/is-there-an-impact-graph-tool-for-non-github-projects) is the nearest thing I've found for this, but obviously doesn't apply for Github. Would rather not reinvent the wheel!

PS: that's not the project I'm interested in embedding, it's just that that one has enough data on it to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those graphs are built dynamically via javascript (d3.js) and SVG. This makes them fairly difficult to extract. However, you might be able to recreate them; inspect the javascript resources on the given page which are used to build the graphs.