# How can I sum up the lines added/removed by a user in a git repo?

Tags: git, scripting

I am trying to find the total number of lines added and total number of lines removed by a user in a git repository. I looked at [How to count total lines changed by a specific author in a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265040/how-to-count-total-lines-changed-by-a-specific-author-in-a-git-repository), which had the command `git log --author="<authorname>" --pretty=tformat: --numstat`, but the answer failed to give a script(however simple) to total the lines changed. What's the simplest way to sum up the lines added/removed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ git log --author="<authorname>" --pretty=tformat: --numstat | perl -ane'
> $i += $F[0]; $d += $F[1]; END{ print "added: $i removed: $d\n"}'
```

Answer (score 3):

Also doable with awk:

```
git log --author="<authorname>" --pretty=tformat: --numstat | awk -F" " '{ added += $1; removed += $2 } END { print "added: ",  added, "removed:", removed }'
```