# how to count SLOC of git library according to date

Tags: python, git

For example, count the SLOC of git with the given date(2 years ago or else).

And I have another question:
    How to figure out the top 10 program files and top 5 components that are modified the most
(have the largest total number of changed lines of code or have the largest number of modifications)in git library with given date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adapt this [ruby script](https://gist.github.com/aslakhellesoy/1683443), which calls `git diff --stat` in order to get those statistics.

For python, you have "[**`git-loc`**](https://github.com/ITikhonov/git-loc)"

```
2010-05-13 14:38:21       42   +44    -2     initial
2010-05-13 14:40:14       44    +3    -1     hashbang added
2010-05-13 14:40:14       49    +8    -3     show last commit too
```

> Run it as `git-loc --svg' to output svg graph on stdout.

See [`git rev-parse` SPECIFYING REVISIONS](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#_specifying_revisions) to check how to use dates:

> **`<refname>@{<date>}`**, e.g. `master@{yesterday}`, `HEAD@{5 minutes ago}`
>
> A ref followed by the suffix `@` with a date specification enclosed in a brace pair (e.g. `{yesterday}`, `{1 month 2 weeks 3 days 1 hour 1 second ago}` or `{1979-02-26 18:30:00}`) specifies the value of the ref at a prior point in time.

You can combine those `git diff` or `git log` commands with "[Finding most changed files in git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7686616/6309)":

```
git log --pretty=format: --name-only | sort | uniq -c | sort -rg | head -10
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is really worked for me. But is there no direct way to find the top 10 files of largest codes changed? I can program it with C or python, what options of 'git log' suit for me? Thank you!

Comment: @CVIn the last part of my answer is suppose to sort the files with the most changes: the 10 first should be the ones you are looking for.