# Find most active area in source code

Tags: git

How do I find the most active area of a repository?
By active i mean the area in the code where there have been the most frequent commit activity, say for the last year?

Comment: Do you want to know which file(s) have been edited the most, or do you want finer granularity: i.e., which lines within which files have been edited the most?  Finding either will require some scripting, but one is definitely easier.

Comment: If file level granularity is enough the question has been answered many times, for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686582/finding-most-changed-files-in-git

Comment: Thx Peter. Your link covers my need right now :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at :[Git Extras](https://github.com/visionmedia/git-extras). Extremely useful and powerful commands. They should be part of Git official source code if you asked me.