# How to find a component with the most commits?

Tags: github, git-commit

As a tester, in the past, I was often able to find a defect-prone component in our system but looking for those which were often changed. In SVN, I knew how to do it but in GitHub, I cannot seem to find the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Finding most changed files in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35225120/6309)", you do have the [git-extras/git-effort](https://github.com/tj/git-extras/blob/master/bin/git-effort) or [git-most](https://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/d34ac0a/scripts/git-most.sh) scripts (which, if it is in your `PATH`, you can call with `git effort` or `git most`, like any `git-xxx` script).
But you need to clone the GitHub repo first.

Example:

```
C:\Users\vonc\data\git\git>git most
......... [wait a long time] .........
1585    Makefile
1060    cache.h
748     gitweb/gitweb.perl
730     refs/files-backend.c
714     diff.c
670     Documentation/config.txt
659     refs.c
624     git-svn.perl
600     sha1_file.c
517     contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
501     builtin/apply.c
499     Documentation/git.txt
491     GIT-VERSION-GEN
433     git-p4.py
413     git.c
407     builtin/pack-objects.c
401     revision.c
376     builtin/commit.c
336     merge-recursive.c
...
```

That doesn't translate directly to GitHub, where you have [the statistics API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/), focused on the *number*  of changes, not the actual list of files.