# Pipes in a Git alias?

Tags: git, bash, unix

I work on feature branches that have annoying big names, so I often end up grepping my current branch name when I need to push up to the feature branch from my local feature branch, like so:

```
git branch | grep '*' | sed 's/* //' | xargs git push origin
```

This works fine. I want to make this an alias, so I did this in `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
   pushcur = branch | grep '*' | sed 's/* //' | xargs git push origin
```

Now, when I run `git pushcur`, I get the following error:

```
usage: git branch [options] [-r | -a] [--merged | --no-merged]
```

Leading me to believe that the alias is not properly parsing the pipes. Is there something else I should do to achieve the desired alias?

Comment: Not related to solving the general problem, but in reasonably recent versions of git, you can configure `push.default` (or `push.origin.default` to limit the effect to `origin`) to `current` (although `upstream` might sometimes be more appropriate).  See the push.default section in [git-config](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).

Comment: consider also using a bash autocompletion to TAB away the branch names! zsh with oh-my-zsh has it by default ;)

Comment: Similar question with additional answer about git aliases: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46528736/git-alias-returns-an-error-when-using-pipe-command/

Comment: I use two aliases to push current pranch:

    cb = rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
    push-me = ! git push origin $(git cb)
    push-mef = ! git push --force origin $(git cb)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

I don't think you can, but you can prefix it with an `!` to treat the command as a new shell command

```
[alias]
    pushcur = ! git branch | grep '*' …
```

Comment: "However, maybe you want to run an external command, rather than a Git subcommand. In that case, you start the command with a ! character." - [git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases)

Comment: This question is the precise reason I came here but the bang pipe quote combination I'm trying fails with "fatal bad config line". I think the real problem is due to the way I'm using quotes. I worked around by eliminating quotes by changing my `sed` pipe to a `tr` pipe. I had to double double escape the backslash so used `...| tr \\\\n`

Comment: Getting the string properly escaped may be a hell sometimes, yes…

Comment: Using the `!` allowed me to include pipes in my alias, but it doesn't maintain the current directory.  You have to include `$GIT_PREFIX` to get back to where you started for subcommands like `ls-files` I had to do `git ls-files $GIT_PREFIX |`....

Comment: How can you pass in input args? This (adding `"$@"`) `pushcur = ! git branch "$@" | grep '*' …` doesn't seem to work. I think I'll just use an actual bash command that I put into `~/bin/git-pushcur` instead of a git alias then. This sitll allows calling it as `git pushcur`.

Comment: Done. Example of what I was talking about in my previous comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66574807/4561887

Comment: @GabrielStaples, generally params are appended to the command, but if you want to put them elsewhere, the trick is to create bash function like `par321 = "!par321() { echo $3 $2 $1 ; } ; par321"` then `git par321 1 2 3` will output `3 2 1`.

Comment: @hacker, perfect. Thanks. This article talks about that too it looks like, under the section "Git Aliases with Functions": https://mikebarkas.dev/2018/git-alias-bash-functions-with-arguments/.

Comment: Aha, I came up with this way before the article was published as probably thousands or millions of other git users (how many are there?) who faced the same problem :)

Comment: this works for me if  I don't leave a space between ! and git, so 

!git myalias | sed 's/ago//'

Answer (score 6):

I typically make small `git-` scripts and put them in a directory that's in my path (`~/.local/bin`). Check out [git-extras](https://github.com/visionmedia/git-extras) for a bunch of good examples.

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround is to add it as **shell alias**.

Here is an example:

```sh
alias grf="git rebase -i $(git merge-base --fork-point master)"
```

(rebase on the fork commit of current branch and master interactively)

For bash, add it to `~/.bashrc`, then you can simply use `grf`.