# git-add only whitespace changes?

Tags: git, whitespace

The style of my project does say to trim trailing whitespace, but this makes diffs very, very messy. I like to consolidate them to one commit before I commit the actual fix.

This is closely related to [Add only non-whitespace changes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3515597/1443496), but it is asking the exact opposite:

> Is there a way to add only the whitespace changes to the staging area?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can try the following "trick":

```
git add -A
git diff --cached -w | git apply --cached -R
```

This basically adds everything to the index, then unstages all changes which affect more than whitespace.

Comment: Related, for creating a git alias: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19525426/1443496. It doesn't appear there is any clever trick to allow piping in an alias, so you must defer to a shell.

Comment: This has slightly strange behavior when the file pre-normalization has two new lines at the tail (where normalization trims this to one).

Comment: @SeanAllred: Admittedly not a case I tested (I usually leave only one newline at the tail). What happens in that case?

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/vermiculus/c7e8943d2187fcc4798f) is printed and the hunk is left unstaged.  I usually leave only one as well, but these files are *very* messy.  I like to think I'm doing a public service.

Comment: I have the prefix disabled, and only got "file is not in index" messages. I needed to add `-p` as option to git apply.

Comment: If you get `error: unrecognized input` you might have set coloring in your git config. Doing `git diff --cached -w --color=never | git apply --cached -R`  (i.e. disabling output coloring in the diff command) solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

here is a bash solution that worked for me

```
for fname in $(git diff --name-only  --diff-filter=ACMR --full-index HEAD)
do
   diff=$(git diff -w --ignore-blank-lines --exit-code $fname)
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      echo "only whitespace diff on $fname ! adding to git..."
      git add $fname
   else
      echo "diff on $fname!"
   fi
done
```

Comment: If your filenames contain spaces, this solution won't work. Modifying it based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/48583007/5078095 was able to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had to combine and modify Tobias' and nneonneo's answer to commit the whitespace of multiple files with large diffs. Make sure to run this from the root of your repository.

```
git add -A
for FILE_NAME in $(git --no-pager diff --name-only --diff-filter=ACMR --full-index HEAD)
do  
    git --no-pager diff --cached -w $FILE_NAME | git apply --cached -R  
done
```

`git --no-pager` prevents the default scrolling that git uses to display large amounts of content. 
The `--name-only` loop allows the command to work on multiple files.