# How to git alias this git complex git command with single and double quotes inside

Tags: git, alias, git-alias

Im trying to create a git alias to this command:

```
git branch -vv | grep ': gone]'|  grep -v "\*" | awk '{ print $1; }' | xargs -r git branch -d
```

I've tried different things: enclosing the command with "", adding ! is needed for the pipes... but I cannot make the command work inside the alias.
Do you have any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pipes in a Git alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525387/pipes-in-a-git-alias)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen No, I know that I need to add ´!´ for the pipe

Answer (score 4):

Don't bother making it an alias. Just drop it into a file named `git-mycommand` somewhere in your `$PATH` (maybe `~/bin`); now you can run `git mycommand` and it will run that script.

Having said that, this might work:

```
git config --global alias.mycommand '!'"git branch -vv | grep ': gone]'|  grep -v '\*' | awk '{ print $1; }' | xargs -r git branch -d"
```

Comment: That command does not work as this is what writes in the .gitconfig file and the behaviour is slightly different
`[alias]
 mycommand = "!git branch -vv | grep ': gone]'|  grep -v '\\*' | awk '{ print ; }' | xargs -r git branch -d"'`

Comment: it behaves differently because of this filtering whis is different from the original command - grep -v '\\*'

Comment: Well, you can fix that :). But I think the non-alias solution is going to be much easier.

Comment: There's a rule, I think attributed to Kernighan, that says that when you're debugging, you only get to use about half your intelligence on the *bug* while using half on the overall problem. So never make your code too clever as you will find it impossible to debug later. :-) In other words, aim for clarity (a script) over cleverness / efficiency (an alias)...

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to wrap the commands in a shell function defined *inside* an alias:

```sh
[alias]
name = "!f() { git branch -vv | grep ': gone]'|  grep -v \"\*\" | awk '{ print $1; }' | xargs -r git branch -d; }; f"
```

An alias that starts with `!` will be interpreted [as a shell command](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases). In this case, you simply define a shell function named `f` and then you invoke directly.

Keep in mind that you'll have to escape any `"` characters inside the function.

Comment: Hi, copy pasting that into the .gitconfig gives bad config error when trying to use git, I think that is not correct. did you try it?
Thanks!