# GIT contribution per author (lines)

Tags: git, line-count

I'm trying to print the per-line contribution of each author to a Git repository.

For that, I use the following command, adapted from [How to count total lines changed by a specific author in a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265040/how-to-count-total-lines-changed-by-a-specific-author-in-a-git-repository)

```
git ls-tree -r -z --name-only HEAD -- */*.c | xargs -0 -n1 git blame \
--line-porcelain HEAD |grep  "^author "|sort|uniq -c|sort -nr
```

However, I get the following error:

```
fatal: cannot stat path 'HEAD': No such file or directory.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay, after more investigation I found this on SO.

> ```
> git ls-files -z | xargs -0n1 git blame -w | perl -n -e '/^.*?\((.*?)\s+[\d]{4}/; print $1,"\n"' | sort -f | uniq -c | sort -n
> ```

The answer came with support from [*Eric Z*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816017/erik-z)

RESULT

> ```
>     234926 USER 1
>      32453 USER 2
>    2941234 USER 3
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This means the first part of your expression is not giving any results. Try

```
git ls-tree -r -z --name-only HEAD -- */*.c
```

without the latter part; probably that gives you empty output. Fix that expression to list the files you want to work on... If I use that in a repository not containing any .c files; it gives me the same error as you. Either removing the option `*/*.c` or fixing it to `*/*.cpp` fixed it (depending on the outcome you want)

Comment: I just get a long list of project files. no author info is included

Comment: if you use your whole command without the `*/*.c` part, you still get the same error?

Comment: if you don't, add the second part etc.. until the error appears; then we can debug further :)

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to @chris-maes accepted answer, this is how to group by file extension:

```
EXTS=$(git ls-files | sed 's/^.*\.//g' | sort | uniq)
for EXT in $EXTS; do
  echo -e "\n$EXT\n"
  git ls-files | 
    grep ".$EXT" | 
    xargs -r -n1 git blame -w | 
    perl -n -e '/^.*?\((.*?)\s+[\d]{4}/; print $1,"\n"' | 
    sort -f | uniq -c | sort -n
done
```

If you wish to filter to specific authors, use a posix regex

```
EXTS=$(git ls-files | sed 's/^.*\.//g' | sort | uniq)
for EXT in $EXTS; do
  echo -e "\n$EXT\n"
  git ls-files | 
    grep ".$EXT" | 
    xargs -r -n1 git blame -w | 
    perl -n -e '/^.*?\((.*?)\s+[\d]{4}/; print $1,"\n"' | 
    sort -f | uniq -c | sort -n |
    grep "James\|McGuigan"
done
```