# How to count up the total lines of every committer in a git repository

Tags: git

I want to count up total lines of every committer in a git repository. I only get a solution below:

```sh
git log --format='%aN' | sort -u | \
  while read name; do
    echo -en "$name\t"
    git log --author="$name" --pretty=tformat: --numstat | \
    awk '{ add += $1; subs += $2; loc += $1 - $2 } END { printf "added lines: %s, removed lines: %s, total lines: %s\n", add, subs, loc }' -
  done
```

It can calculate out ***ALL HISTORY*** of every committer's total lines. But I want to calculate out in **CURRENT** snapshot, every committer's total lines. I don't know how to do it.

Do you have a solution about this problem?

Comment: I think you're on the right track (some variation of `git log...` + a sed or awk script).  Look [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History) and [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) for some additional options.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GIT contribution per author (lines)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449075/git-contribution-per-author-lines)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+count+contribution+per+author

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit overkill and slow but you can do something like this.

```sh
git log --format='%aN' | sort -u | \
  while read name; do
    echo -en "$name\t"
    for FILE in $(git ls-files) ; do git blame $FILE | grep "$name" ; done | wc -l
  done
```

Comment: I suggest adding some stderr redirections `2> /dev/null` so that git errors do not cover the author names :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the accepted answer slow and broke for me with GPG signed commits.

This worked:

```sh
git ls-files | xargs -n1 git blame --line-porcelain | sed -n 's/^author //p' | sort -f | uniq -ic | sort -nr
```