# git: amount of chars in HEAD contributed by an author

Tags: bash, git

We use git/GitLab to collaborate on a project which involves digitizing/proof-reading of old/ancient books. Editors are paid per contributed chars. Till now we used something like `wc -m *` to find out how many chars were contributed. This approach assumes that all files are contributed by one person AND that all files contributed by that person are in the current directory. Real situation is actually different. Editors may fix each others' files and their files might be spread over several directories.

Is there a way in git (probably involving `--author=` flag) to find out the amount of characters contributed by an author in the whole repository in HEAD (i.e. its current state, not accumulative amount of chars in all history). Maybe using Bash/pipes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GIT contribution per author (lines)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449075/git-contribution-per-author-lines)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+count+contribution+by+author

Comment: @phd - it counts lines, doesn't it? I need chars...

Comment: You're going to have to do something like scraping the output of `git log --author=soso -p --=word-diff`

Comment: How do you define "amount of characters contributed"? Does it only include adding of new characters? How does removal of characters count toward the amount?

Comment: @ShangjianDing - removal doesn't count. Only characters that are currently there.