# Use git to get line count for one developer day/week

Tags: git, github

Is there any way to use git to get the amount of lines a particular developer committed on a given day/week?

I understand that you can count the total lines an author has committed like so: [How to count total lines changed by a specific author in a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265040/how-to-count-total-lines-changed-by-a-specific-author-in-a-git-repository), but it would be useful to segment by day or week.

**Update**

The best solution I could find to this was to combine an answer from here: [How to count total lines changed by a specific author in a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265040/how-to-count-total-lines-changed-by-a-specific-author-in-a-git-repository) with the --since and --before filters mentioned below:

```
git log --author="<author>" --since=“<date>” --before=“<date>” --pretty=tformat: --numstat | awk '{ add += $1; subs += $2; loc += $1 - $2 } END { printf "added lines: %s, removed lines: %s, total lines: %s\n", add, subs, loc }' -
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265040/how-to-count-total-lines-changed-by-a-specific-author-in-a-git-repository use --since --before etc to filter by date.

Comment: Aha, thanks, that looks like what I need. The since/before filters don't seem to be mentioned in that answer though.

Comment: That's why I mentioned it.  You should be able to add --since and --before arguments to the command listed in the other answer to filter to date ranges.  http://gitref.org/inspect/ for more info

Comment: Is someone going to get fired?

Comment: Ha, to track myself, actually