# Calculate diff between two branches sorted by author

Tags: git

Is there an easy way to calculate the changes (lines added, lines deleted...) grouped by Author, between two commits?

How many changes do Author X made in a feature branch, that are not in the master branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will output the number of added/removed lines for a given author introduced in `<branch>` compared to `master`:

```
git log master..<branch> --author="<author>" --pretty=tformat: --numstat \
| gawk '{ add += $1; subs += $2; loc += $1 - $2 } END { printf "added lines: %s removed lines: %s total lines: %s\n", add, subs, loc }' -
```

Substitute `<branch>` and `<author>` (could be a part of author's name) accordingly.
I have slightly modified solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7010890/7018603) answer, in order to filter commits out.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple options: `git diff` or `git log`.

The `git diff` command will show you the changes to tracked files in your work tree that haven't been added to the index.

The `git log` command lets you do things like list project history, filter it, or search for specific changes.  `git log --author="<pattern>"` will search commits by a particular author.

Each command of course has a lot of different options that you can use to find the specific information that you are looking for.

['git diff' Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

['git log' Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I was asking for a specific command to combine them both. I ;m familiar with the documentation.