# How can I find who edited all staged lines?

Tags: git, blame

I have a project that I need to code review (and fix), and I need to trace back who did it. I have edited all relevant lines in the project, and now I would like to see a summary of who was the last editor to these lines. I have a guess that it was all the same user, so I'd like some statistics.

I want to find whose lines I have edited the most in the currently staged lines (or commit, I am going to commit that anyway). I want a list of names that I need to count each user in, or immediately a summary of amount of lines (from the currently staged lines) that have been edited per user.

I have tried googling, but my Google-fu has fallen short.

Comment: If you use Visual Studio, you can right-click on any line and select `Source Control -> Annotate`. I don't think this functionality is limited to Visual Studio, because it works regardless of whether the project is using `Git` or `TFS` (or, I guess, `SVN`).

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to manually tally the users. I want to do this using the commandline

Comment: Maybe this could be useful? The second answer from the top mentions git-quick-stats. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265040/how-to-count-total-lines-changed-by-a-specific-author-in-a-git-repository