# Git: Average and total lines changed in a date range

Tags: git

In git, for a given date range and a given user, I'd like to find out:

1 - The total lines changed.

2 - The average lines changed per day.

**Note**: This question is **not** a duplicate of [How to count total lines changed by a specific author in a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265040/how-to-count-total-lines-changed-by-a-specific-author-in-a-git-repository) because the answers to that question don't limit the results by date.  I'd like the results limited to a given date range.  That question also doesn't address average lines changed per day at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count total lines changed by a specific author in a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265040/how-to-count-total-lines-changed-by-a-specific-author-in-a-git-repository)

Comment: Thanks, but the answers there don't limit the results to a given date range.  They're all grand totals across all commits.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For instance

`git log --since=2017-01-01 --until=2017-06-01 --author="Jim" --format= --numstat | awk '{s+=$1; s+=$2} END {print s}'`

gives me the sum of *insertions* and *deletions* for that timespan and author. For the average, [this answer on unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24626/quickly-calculate-date-differences) looks fine to get the difference between two dates in days. The rest is trivial.