# Legal issue and using Git history to get percentage of mass of work

Tags: git

I have a legal issue with old partners who stole my work.

I am trying to use the Git log (that I kept) to prove the mass of work I did (I did most of it, but the problem is to be able to *prove* it...)

However, the Git log only contains dates and a list of modified/created files. Not the weight of these files, or the number of lines, or whatever...

I did what I could, i.e. calculate the percentage of contributions to the Git repository.

But now, the opposing party is trying to get my legal action cancelled, pretending that I have no proof whatsoever.

I don't understand how that's possible, given that I provided dozens of emails, the full history of the code, and plenty other things... But that's another story.

I *have* to get the hardest proofs possible. How can I do that better than I already did?

Any advice is appreciated!

Cheers,

Comment: What do you mean by "git log"? Output of `git log`? Running `git log --stat` shows the numbers of changed lines, too.

Comment: This might help: [How to count total lines changed by a specific author in a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1265040/3282436)

Comment: I have used [git-quick-stats](https://github.com/arzzen/git-quick-stats) for getting a rough overview of different authors percentage of work in a repo. It is mentioned in the link in the comment posted by @0x5453 . git-quick-stats creates nice reports. It might be what you are looking for.

Comment: To protect your future work, GPG-sign may help. https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#git-commit--Sltkeyidgt and https://help.github.com/articles/signing-commits-using-gpg/

Comment: @ElpieKay thank you for this input! There is also a mechanism in France called "Soleau envelope" that mainly protect ideas or work done by a single person, if I'm not mistaken. Alas, it was too late for me.

0x5453 and Mr.Christer: Thanks, I'll try to use that (whichever is the more efficient)! I deleted the remote repository (it was mine too) and I thought I deleted my local copy, but I just found out I did not!! :) :)

choroba: as stated above, I just found out I still have my local repo. I'll try that too (I think I only had a raw git log output, without lines or weights)

Thx all!!

Comment: @Mr.Christer I had a look at git-quick-stats, but it seems it only shows the number of commits per person, and it does not help me, because I already have this, and also I need more precise stats because my old partner used to commit multiple times a day, whereas I did commit only a couple times per week, therefore unfairly weighing the stats in his favor...

Comment: @Mr.Christer [EDIT] I'm mistaken, it is in fact really cool and gave me all the stats I needed!!! Thanks a lot!! :) :)

Comment: Be aware, git history can be rewritten rather easily. If there isn't a copy on an independent third-party that is not under either your or their control, then simply providing a history from the git repo on your laptop probably isn't going to be sufficient. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/change-the-author-and-committer-name-and-e-mail-of-multiple-commits-in-git

Comment: @EqualityInTech thanks for this. Yeah, I figured. The problem is, I deleted the distant repo that I owned when I left (was forced to) the company. I asked them, and they told me that apart from a court order, they can't do anything (they can't give me the logs). Maybe I'll ask them again... But I can't do nothing more, I'm afraid :(