# How can I calculate the number of lines changed between two versions in git by an author?

Tags: git, version, line, diff, author

Is there any way to calculate the number of lines changed between two versions in git by an author?

Between two versions without author, the command is:

```
git diff v0.6.0 v0.7.0 --shortstat
 1752 files changed, 79218 insertions(+), 150134 deletions(-)
```

But I would like to see the line changes between versions and authors.

That would be very nice.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265040/how-to-count-total-lines-changed-by-a-specific-author-in-a-git-repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the solution:

git log v0.6.0 v0.7.0 --author="Maier"  --oneline --shortstat

Thank you very much!

Best regards